# How to verify methods with list as arguments using Typemock

Tags: c#, unit-testing

In one of my tests in C# using typemock, I need to verify if a function is called with some argument or not. The argument happens to be List. and the method is protected.

The following is the signature of the method whose call is to be verified

```
protected void SomeMethod(List<double> someArgs);
```

The following is the verify code I wrote

```
List<double> someArgs = new List<double>();
Isolate.Verify.NonPublic.WasCalled(someObject, SomeMethod).WithArguments(someArgs);
```

I keep getting **"method called with mismatched arguments which is a VerifyException"**. Does this mean Isolator cannot verify if the argument is a list and can only work with simple types like string, double, int etc? Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: I don't use Typemock but it could be checking for reference equality rather than that the list has the same elements.

Comment: @Scroog1 Yes, I feel the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer: I use `MOQ` and am only going by what seems equivalent from Typemock docs**

`MOQ` has `It.Is.Any<List<double>>()` to verify that an argument of the specified type is used. Unless you care that the exact object was passed....but that is probably over-specifying your test. Even this test runs borderline over-specification.

Going through the docs it appears that [this is what you want](http://docs.typemock.com/isolator/Default.aspx##Ref.chm/html/M_TypeMock_ArrangeActAssert_IArgumentsMatcher_Matching.htm)...Here is what the code would probably look like

```
Isolate.Verify.NonPublic.WasCalledWithArguments(someObject=>SomeMethod(null))
    .Matching(args => args[0] is List<double>);
```

Comment: Thanks. The method under test has return type void and only check that can be done is whether it called another function with correct arguments. Isolator doesn't provide NonPublic.WasCalledWithArguments. There is only WasCalled and that's the issue.